# react-native-elements, help center input text within FormInput

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm using forms from [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/forms.html) and would like to center the input text. I've tried, `alignSelf: 'center'` as well as `flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'` without any luck. All text continues to remain left aligned.

[image: a]

JFYI, I'm making adjustments to the `inputStyle` [prop](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/forms.html#inputstyle).

```
<FormInput 
  ...
  inputStyle={styles.formInputText}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`textAlign`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props#textalign) attribute

```
<FormInput 
  ...
  inputStyle={styles.formInputText}
  textAlign={'center'}
/>
```

Also, you may want to upgrade your package as it looks like `FormInput` has been deprecated [according to the docs](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/e2dcb4e4696b06e80d718668d60470f72c4e86f8/docs/troubleshooting.md#importing-a-component-from-the-wrong-version)...

> `<FormInput />` is only available in v0.19.1 and below. `<Input />` is only
>   available in `v1.0.0-beta1` and higher.

Comment: Awesome. That did the trick! I also ended up using `alignSelf: 'center'` to get it truly in the center.